# One DocumentRoot, Multiple Domains, Adding www but no htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have multiple domains pointing to the same folder, but I'd like some to be www and some non-www. Right now something is causing all of them to go straight to the www version and I am not sure why.

I have one VirtualHost setup with ServerAlias for all the domains as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/domain1"
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain3.com
    ServerAlias www.domain3.com
    ServerAlias domain4.com
    ServerAlias www.domain4.com
    ErrorLog  "c:/logs/www/domain1-error.log"
    #CustomLog "c:/logs/www/domain1-access.log" common
    CustomLog "| c:/Apache24/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/logs/www/domain1/access-%Y_%m_%d.log 86400 -300" combined
    # php version #
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to figure out why http://domain3.com/info.php goes to http://www.domain3.com/info.php and so on.

How can I get it to stay at http://domain3.com/info.php and even get http://www.domain3.com/info.php to switch to http://domain3.com/info.php

I'd like to figure out if this in an Apache setting as I understand I can use htaccess to change around www or not, but right now I don't have any htaccess in the DocumentRoot folder and it's still redirecting to www for everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post us your Apache config - you don't need (and shouldn't use) .htaccess if you've got access to the actual `<VirtualHost>` section, which it sounds like you have, but it would be good to see that, and any other custom configuration it might be inheriting at the server level.

Comment: We do have access. It's a WAMP/Windows server and I updated the code above for formatting and content for the VirtualHost. We are using basically the default for Apache with FastCGI PHP and AllowOverride All in the directorie tags.